# Pandas merge 2 dataframes based on multiple matching column values

Tags: python, pandas

First dataframe  df1:

```
seq  id                a1        a2   
12  209981             None    None
12  209982            Funds    None
13  209983      Free_Income    None
13  209984      Free_Income    None
14  209985      Free_Income  Hybrid
```

and my second dataframe df2 :

```
   seq              a1     p1    p2     
   12              Funds  5.71  1.09  
   12        Free_Income  2.18  3.17  
   12             Hybrid  2.88  3.70
   13        Free_Income  2.53  2.64  
   13              Funds  7.08  3.09 
   13             Hybrid  7.28  3.99  
   14        Free_Income  4.53  2.25  
   14             Hybrid  1.89  2.45  
   14              Funds  1.13  2.35
```

Now I want the output in below format

```
seq  id                a1          a2    p1    p2   p3   p4
12  209981             None      None   None  None  None None 
12  209982            Funds      None   5.71  1.09  None None 
13  209983      Free_Income      None   2.53  2.64  None None
13  209984      Free_Income      None   2.53  2.64  None None
14  209985      Free_Income    Hybrid   4.53  2.25  1.89 2.45
```

The mapping is

df1.seq = df2.seq

df1.a1=df2.a1

df1.a2=df2.a1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to merge twice.  The first merge focus on `a1` in the left dataframe and `a1` in the right dataframe.  The second merge you switch focus to `a2` from the left dataframe.

```
df1.merge(
    df2,
    left_on=['seq', 'a1'],
    right_on=['seq', 'a1'],
    how='left'
).join(
    df1.merge(
        df2,
        left_on=['seq', 'a2'],
        right_on=['seq', 'a1'],
        how='left'
    )[['p1', 'p2']].rename(columns=dict(p1='p3', p2='p4'))
)

   seq      id           a1      a2    p1    p2    p3    p4
0   12  209981         None    None   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   12  209982        Funds    None  5.71  1.09   NaN   NaN
2   13  209983  Free_Income    None  2.53  2.64   NaN   NaN
3   13  209984  Free_Income    None  2.53  2.64   NaN   NaN
4   14  209985  Free_Income  Hybrid  4.53  2.25  1.89  2.45
```

---

Comment: I am extremely sorry piRSquared , I have to change the expected o/p format here

Comment: Thanks a lot @piRSquared , will integrate with my real code and respond